Network spikes (stutters) for 2 seconds at least every 5 minutes
I’m using a fiber network with a Huawei HG8245W5-6T router. While playing games or performing tasks that involve UDP traffic, the network experiences short lags lasting a few seconds before returning to normal. For example, in LoL the ping flow is as follows: 24ms -> 2 seconds lag -> 24ms again.
Initially, I thought the problem was caused by the Wi-Fi adapter: I was using a 5G TP-LINK Archer T4U Plus, so I replaced it with an ASUS AC58, which also supports 5G. However, the problem persisted.
To debug the issue, I ran the following ping tests:

ping to another local machine: ping 192.168.1.58
ping to the router server: ping 192.168.1.1
ping to an external service: ping google.ru

All of these tests showed packet loss at the exact same time, which led me to believe the issue is with the router:
Sun Dec  8 01:27:35 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1216 ttl=64 time=6.415 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:36 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1217 ttl=64 time=6.130 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:37 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1218 ttl=64 time=2.958 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:38 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1219 ttl=64 time=2.664 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:39 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1220 ttl=64 time=3.188 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:40 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1221 ttl=64 time=3.342 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:42 CET 2024: Request timeout for icmp_seq 1222
Sun Dec  8 01:27:43 CET 2024: Request timeout for icmp_seq 1223
Sun Dec  8 01:27:43 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1224 ttl=64 time=6.741 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:44 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1225 ttl=64 time=3.048 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:45 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1226 ttl=64 time=2.751 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:46 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1227 ttl=64 time=3.248 ms
Sun Dec  8 01:27:47 CET 2024: 64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1228 ttl=64 time=2.373 ms

What steps can I take to localize and resolve this problem?
